# Several of my ubuntu apps arent opening at all

Tags: gnome-terminal, update-manager, 18.10

Most of the apps that I currently need aren't working, even after restarting several times and trying many online suggestions. It started when I tried upgrading from Ubuntu 18.10 to 19.04. I opened the software updater and it gave me an error about my python3 file being corrupted or something similar. I found a guide on how to fix this and i ran the following command: `sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python` but I realized that was for a different version of python(after I ran it). When I tried to open the software updater again, it wouldn't open. I looked up solutions to start this from terminal or other places, but found that the terminal didn't open either. I don't know what's happening, and I'm too much of a linux noob to fix it, so I'm asking on here.